# Unable to build avro from the trunk due to plexus XmlStreamWriter failure in shade-plugin

Tags: maven, avro, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to build apache avro by cloning it from the trunk https://github.com/apache/avro.git but it is failing with the following error for me.

```
cd lang/java/avro

mvn clean install

[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.5.3:bundle (default-bundle) @ avro ---
[WARNING] Bundle org.apache.avro:avro:bundle:1.9.0-SNAPSHOT : Split package, multiple jars provide the same package:org/apache/avro
Use Import/Export Package directive -split-package:=(merge-first|merge-last|error|first) to get rid of this warning
Package found in   [Jar:., Jar:avro-guava-dependencies]
Class path         [Jar:., Jar:plexus-utils, Jar:avro-guava-dependencies, Jar:findbugs-annotations, Jar:jackson-core-asl, Jar:jackson-mapper-asl, Jar:paranamer, Jar:snappy-java, Jar:commons-compress, Jar:xz, Jar:joda-time, Jar:slf4j-api, Jar:slf4j-simple]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-site-plugin:3.0:attach-descriptor (attach-descriptor) @ avro ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.5:test-jar (default) @ avro ---
[INFO] Building jar: ~/work/git/opensource/avro.upstream/avro/lang/java/avro/target/avro-1.9.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:1.7.1:shade (default) @ avro ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/util/xml/XmlStreamWriter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:658)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:882)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1038)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.XmlStreamWriter
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 55 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.578 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-08T12:17:52-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 43M/573M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:1.7.1:shade (default) on project avro: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:1.7.1:shade failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:1.7.1:shade: org/codehaus/plexus/util/xml/XmlStreamWriter
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:1.7.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/1.7.1/maven-shade-plugin-1.7.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:~/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[project>org.apache.avro:avro:1.9.0-SNAPSHOT, parent: ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.XmlStreamWriter
```

Comment: Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: Apache Maven 3.3.9 (2015-11-10T08:41:47-08:00)

Java version: 1.8.0_71

OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Comment: Would please upgrade maven-shade-plugin to a current version http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Comment: That fixes it. Thx a lot !